# Python- how to convert .txt file (two columns) to dictionary elements?

Tags: python, file, dictionary, text, key

I want to check min and max of x and y from two columns of .txt file, but I don't know how.

Hi guys :) I did an spectral analysis and I got over 500 lines of frequency and  corresponding dB. I wanted to create a dictionary in jupyter notebook that will  allow me to check the max and min value of x and y and changes in few spectral analysis. I used this code:

```
y = {} 

with open('wow.txt', "r") as infile: 
    for line in infile: 
        key, value = line.strip().split(':') 
        y[key] = (value) 
print(y)
```

and also

```
d = {}
with open('wow.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split(':')
        d[key] = int(value)
```

But there is an

> ValueError : not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1).

I got this values from programme and there are two columns, so what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere in the text file, there is no ':' character, so it can't split the line. Maybe an empty line somewhere?

Also, for this kind of things, I like to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), a library that has quite some interesting functions for this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=':', names=['freq', 'db'])
min = df.loc[df['db'].idxmin()]
max = df.loc[df['db'].idxmax()]
print('Minimum at {}Hz with a magnitude of {}dB'.format(min['freq'], min['db']))
print('Maximum at {}Hz with a magnitude of {}dB'.format(max['freq'], max['db']))
```

Comment: Your code works, thank you  :) but there is another problem. The minimum value is incorrect. The smallest frequency value in my list is 43,066406 Hz but the programme starts checking the values after exceeding the threshold of 10,000 Hz.

Comment: Oh sorry, if you use `df.min()`, it gets the minimum values of each column separately. I'll update the answer.

Comment: But values returned from df.min() and df.max() are strange. One column is for frequency, the other one for dB. Programme sliced first column in two sections. For example I will use this: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,] : [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12].  Programme said the max is 3:9 and the minimum is 4:10.                                                                                                                   And this new code have another error :( TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [nan] of <class 'float'>

Comment: If you can upload your data file (or part of, if it's _very_ long) to https://pastebin.com/ or something like that and share a link here, I can take a look into it further